# How to call and use Rest full services in codegnighter

Tags: codeigniter, rest

Actually I am working on codegnighter and I want to use Restful xml service at place of database in my project but I don't know is there any default methods or functions of codegnighter to get the xml or restful service response.

Please help me 
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Phil Sturgeon's REST_Controller](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver/blob/master/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php) is a good place to start.